# having problems posting data to the backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, vite, mern

i am developing a MERN website for the first time and i face problem with the signup functionality when i post the data it give me a **400 Bad Request** response

this is the signup backend controller:

```
// handling signup
export const signupControl = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fullname, matric, password, matricImage } = req.body;

    // check if matric already exist
    const user = await User.findOne({ matric });
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: `matric already exist` });
    }

    // check if password length is less than 8
    const passLength = password;
    if (passLength.length < 8) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "password is less than 8" });
    }

    // crypt password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    // create new user
    const newUser = User.create({
      fullname,
      matric,
      password: hashedPass,
      matricImage,
    });

    if (newUser) {
      generateTokenAndCookie((await newUser)._id, res);
      (await newUser).save();

      res.status(200).json({
        _id: (await newUser)._id,
        fullname: (await newUser).fullname,
        matric: (await newUser).matric,
        password: (await newUser).password,
        matricImage: (await newUser).matricImage,
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "invalid user data" });
      console.log("error");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: `${err.message}` });
  }
};
```

and here is the frontend code where i bring the data and submit them:

const Signup = () => {
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
fullname: "",
matric: "",
password: "",
matricImage: "",
});

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

```
const formData = {
  fullname: inputs.fullname,
  matric: inputs.matric.trim(), // Trim whitespace
  password: inputs.password,
  matricImage: inputs.matricImage,
};

console.log(formData);

try {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth/signup", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  });

  const data = await response.json();
} catch (error) {
  toast.error(error.message);
}
```

};

i assign all the data from the inputs forms inside a variable called formData which formatted according to the backend need, same data format i used when testing on postman and worked for me.
also i tried submitting different values and still no changes

**NOTES**
when i consloe log the formData it give me same needed data for the backend =
{
"fullname": "ahmed omar",
"matric": "b032219461",
"password": "1234567890",
"matricImage": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAaI"
}

also both servers(frontend, backend) are running during the proccess still facing the problem

and when tested on postman it works.
however when i write data in the frontend form and post them via fetch request it give me a 400 bad request response, still dont know where in the frontend is the problem since its a 400 response then it must be from the frontend right ?

Comment: Have you handled `cors`?

Comment: your code can return HTTP 400 in at least 3 places - which one is doing it?

Comment: by the way, if you `const newUser = await User.create({` - then you won't need to `(await newUser).whatever` a dozen times ... also, the `if (newUser) {` since `newUser` will ALWAYS (in your current code) be a Promise so, the `if` is redundant

Comment: You should learn more about debugging in NodeJS. It really helps you know how your program works, what line code runs, what line code errors. It make you know where error occurs.